# Why use `exec_statement` when writing PyInstaller hooks?

Tags: pyinstaller

In the [PyInstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks) they demonstrate the use of `eval_statement()` and `exec_statement()` which call `eval()` or `exec()` in a new instance of Python. But they don't say why you would want to run your code in a separate instance.

For example, why couldn't their example of:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import exec_statement

mpl_data_dir = exec_statement(
   "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib._get_data_path())"
   )
datas = [ (mpl_data_dir, "") ]
```

not just be:

```
import matplotlib
datas = [(matplotlib._get_data_path(), "")]
```

I've tried doing this with my own library and it doesn't seem to do it any harm. So why the extra complexity? Why do all the other hooks included in PyInstaller use the 1st method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the hooks use the first method in case of path and environment manipulations. What happens if matplotlib changes `sys.path` or some other environmental manipulation that could mess with the build process? Using a separate python instance means this won't happen.